# Can someone help me with this React tutorial syntax error?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Hi guys I've been trying to learn React with their tutorial online. I copy and pasted the code into Visual Studio Code and when ever I run demo.html, the page is blank. I got to the console and find that their is a syntax error " Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' " How can this be if I've just done a copy and paste job? I don't know if it could be something to do with the javascript being in a separate file?

I get the concepts behind this code but I can't see to figure out why it's working.
Any help if much appreciated!

Here is the script called test.js

```
function Welcome(props) {  return <h1> Hello {props.name} </h1>;
}

const element = <Welcome name="Sara" />;ReactDOM.render(
element,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And here is demo.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Add React in One Minute</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- We will put our React component inside this div. -->
    
    <div id='root'></div>

    <!-- Load React. -->
    <!-- Note: when deploying, replace "development.js" with "production.min.js". -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <!-- Load our React component. -->
    <script src="test.js"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If you are developing React project. It is always a best practice and recommended by React team to
> use `CLI` and get rid of all these script tags inclusion. [Read React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#recommended-toolchains)

You have to set Babel also to compile JSX. For that, you have to include it

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
```

and add `type` attribute to the `script` tag

```
type="text/babel"
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Add React in One Minute</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- We will put our React component inside this div. -->

  <div id='root'></div>

  <!-- Load React. -->
  <!-- Note: when deploying, replace "development.js" with "production.min.js". -->

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Load our React component. -->
  <script src="test.js" type="text/babel"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to give an explanation!

Comment: Glad I could help. Read docs as much as possible

Answer (score 2):

React uses a special file type called JSX which allows you to include HTML like syntax in Javascript. In order to parse JSX files you need to setup a react project.

The simplest way to do so is to use the Javascript library [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started).
To use that install [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) and then execute `npx create-react-app my-app` to get some boiler plate code.

You can then navigate into the newly created react project using `cd my-app` and start it using `npm start`. This will start a server on port 3000. You can then navigate to http://localhost:3000 to view your react application.

You can configure the react project to start and debug it through VSCode as outlined here [Configure the debugger](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/reactjs-tutorial#_configure-the-debugger).